# Analysing a JVisualVM profile - finding the source of large numbers of primitive types?

Tags: java, profiling

I am trying to reduce the memory footprint of my application. JVisualVM heap dumps report that the objects taking up the most space are:

- char[]
- byte[]
- int[]

Which isn't particularly helpful. How can I track these objects back to the parent classes that are holding them?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

VisualVM does compute retained size. You have to add the column manually, the default view doesn't seem to have it though.

Comment: Do you know how to do it? There is a way to find top instances by retained size, but I can't get the same measure for class level.

Comment: @lightoze: (10 years later) In the VisualVM heap dump view, you can select to group entries on classes or instances using the "Aggregation" button just above the list.

Answer (score 3):

Those primitive arrays are likely to be the internal state of things like `String`, which keeps its state in a `char[]`. A good profiler will understand this, and will have the notion of "retained size", which describes the size of objects including the size of their sub-objects. This would indicate that `String` was taking up the space, not `char[]`.

However, I see no mentioned of "retained size" in VisualVM. It doesn't seem to have the proper profiling capabilities of the commercial alternatives.

To see what I'm talking about, try downloading an evaluation of [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/index.jsp), and connect that to your app. It's a lot more complex than VisualVM, but it can give you the retained size of the heap objects, and it's quite illuminating. It will also show you what is referencing each of the objects on the heap, so you can trace leaks.

Comment: A tiny update 12 years later: `String` nowdays stores its data in `byte[]`. And VisualVM does compute retained sizes. :)